# how to check ng-show={{}} expression with arraylist of values whether its matching or not?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am trying to check evaluate each ng-repeat list array with multiple objects.
is there a way to achieve this ?

Please find below code for your reference.

```
    **<div ng-repeat="i in items" ng-show="items.id === arrayList[]" />

$scope.arrayList = [{"id":"1"},{"id":"2"},...]**
```

i need to check whether items.id is matching with any of arraylist object.id or not . Can any one please help me.

i in items is from api service

Comment: create a function like that in the scope

Answer (score 2):

View chunk:

```
<div ng-repeat="i in items" ng-show="inList(items.id)" />
```

In your controller:

```
//you already have $scope.arrayList
$scope.inList = function(id) {
    return $scope.arrayList.some(function(i, v) { return v.id == id });
};
```

Comment: now it is checked against `v.id` where `v` is each element in the array

Comment: A more efficient/clever answer but his was up first--you both get a point. :)

Answer (score 2):

write some function in controller such this .

```
  $scope.isMatch = function(id) {
    for(var i =0; i < arrayList.length; i ++){
       if(arrayList[i].id === id){
          return true;
       }
    }
    return false;    
  }
```

then use it in view.

```
ng-show="isMatch(i.id)"
```